# How to filter meta data by user-defined statements in R?

Tags: r, filter, metadata, text-mining, tm

There is a function called `sFilter` in R to filter meta data. However, [the function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/sFilter) is an old (Version: 0.5-10) tm package. Is there any function instead of it in a new version?

My code block is;

```
query <- "LEWISSPLIT == 'TRAIN'"
trainData <- tm_filter(Corpus, FUN = sFilter, query)
```

It means, get documents which have "TRAIN" value in their LEWISSPLIT attribute.

```
<REUTERS TOPICS=?? LEWISSPLIT=?? CGISPLIT=?? OLDID=?? NEWID=??>
```

Comment: Have a look at `meta()`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I did. But i don't know how can i use it instead of sFilter in tm_filter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your own filtering function:

```
trainData <- tm_filter(Corpus, FUN = function(x, qry) any(meta(x)["lewissplit"] == qry), "TRAIN")
```

This was adapted from `example(tm_filter)`. There is an example using `grep()` for more flexible search.